# How to add permissions on existing temporal document for the role in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

The MarkLogic database with temporal functionality contains data with permissions assigned to specific roles. However, we now need to grant read access to a particular role for temporal documents. I have attempted to utilize a MarkLogic function to enable this read permission.

```
 xdmp:document-add-permissions(
                           "/entities/abc.xml",
                           (xdmp:permission("read-user", "read"))
                           )
```

But getting the below error:

> 1.0-ml] SEC-TEMPORALDOC: xdmp:document-add-permissions("/entities/abc.xml",
> <sec:permission xmlns:sec="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/security">
> sec:capability...</sec:capability>...</sec:permission>)
> -- Cannot perform non-temporal operation on document in temporal collection

Kindly suggest how can I provide the new permissions on temporal documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message states, you cannot perform non-temporal operations on temporal documents.

Use the temporal function [`temporal:document-insert()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/temporal:document-insert) and set the appropriate options with the permissions you want to set.